# Why is Vue event not being caught in parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to Vue and trying to get the hang of the trivial example of sending an event from a child component. I have a child component, `vehicle`, and I want to fire an event on the parent when it is selected. I have a method on the component as follows:

```
    triggerSelect() {
        console.log("Selecting vehicle");
        this.$emit('select-vehicle', this.vehicleData);
    }
```

This method works. I see the printout in the console and I can verify with the Vue devtools extension that the event is firing properly. Then in my main HTML file, I have the vehicle component within a div, as so:

```
        <div class="col-2" v-on:select-vehicle="selectVehicle">
            <vehicle 
                v-for="vehicle in vehicles"
                v-bind:key="vehicle.id"
                v-bind:vehicle-data="vehicle"
                >
            </vehicle>
        </div>
```

The div has the v-on linked to a selectVehicle method, but this method never get fired. no errors in the console either. Am I making some glaring mistake in my usage of event handling? I've closely followed the Vue docs and this seems right. Is it a problem that I'm trying to capture the event from a div rather than a proper component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is exactly the problem. From `v-on` documentation (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on):

> When used on a normal element, it listens to native DOM events only.
> When used on a custom element component, it listens to custom events
> emitted on that child component.